# onerror javascript loads just once?

Tags: javascript, html, onerror

I've been trying to figure out the way for loading screen on/off as I choose (not by automatical event).
so I came up with this solution:

css:

```
#loading {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.5);
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnyxU.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

javascript:

```
function loading(action) {
    console.log(action);
    document.getElementById('loading').style.display = action ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

html:

```
<div id=loading></div>
<img onerror="loading(true)">
// do whatever i need, which takes several seconds to load
<img onerror="loading(false)">
```

the loading screen comes on as suppose to, with no problem whatsoever, however there are two things which are not clear to me...

1. the **console.log(action)** does not work... it just won't print anything to console whatsoever
2. second image won't turn off the loading screen... it just stays on all the time

what do I do wrong here?

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect to happen, but the `onerror` handler only gets called by an `img` element when there is an error loading the image.

Comment: exactly, this is an old trick how to trigger any javascipt call :) so there is no src in that img as you can see, because of that i can trigger onerror event which will call my javascript function to shot/hide loading screen... showing works fines, hiding not so much :(

Comment: I don't think it does. Your `#loading` div is already visible at the start (`display: block;`), `onerror` is just not called at all. It would be called if you had a fake `src` attribute on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @Aioros answer, it was partialy correct...
after adding src to both  tags, then it tries to trigger the javascript function, however i was gettig error: **loading is not a function** which makes no sence to me.

so i have replaced:

```
<img src=blabla onerror="loading(true/false)">
```

with:

```
<script>loading(true/false)</script>
```

and it works just fine now...